# Image picker error having a dash across pickimage

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

May I know why is there a dash across the pickImage?
Below is part of the code that I have written.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

class _CreateCCAState extends State<CreateCCA> {
  String _name, _description, _contact, _cat;
  File _image;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is no longer using the static method instead now class object must be created, which seems good update in lib

```
ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

Also, in the documentation it clearly said

> @Deprecated('Use imagePicker.getImage() method instead.')
>
> static Future pickImage(

Answer (score 1):

> May I know why is there a dash across the pickImage?

Because it is deprecated, so thats a warning to not use the method `pickImage`.

You have to use the method `getImage()`:

```
  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }
```

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker